# How Do I make a batch File Press enter?

Tags: batch-file

```
I have this code so far 
@echo off
echo Starting Garry's Mod
start hl2.exe

TIMEOUT /T 15

echo Starting HealthBarsPub
start HealthbarsPub.exe

exit
```

---

I'm trying to make it so after it runs HealthBarsPub it presses enter. any ideas???

Comment: Are you trying to send the enter to HealthbarsPub.exe, or do you just need to send an enter to the command prompt for some reason?

Comment: Well the program opens a prompt, there's 2 options YES and NO its hovering over YES which is the one I want... so all I need is for it to hit ENTER

Comment: Is it a pop-up? Batch can't interact with GUIs.